# installing twitter and oauth on drupal

Tags: authentication-authorization, social-network

I have just been trying to get twitter going on my drupal 7.21 website.  i followed the tutorial at http://drupal.org/node/1346824 
Everything was fine until the last step of authorising a twitter account, when i got a blank page back from the twitter app and a message saying "unauthorised oauth request".  I've tried re-installing, messing with callback URL's etc but cannot get anything to work. Has anyone else solved this problem?
Thanks
Andy

Comment: Is your server behind a firewall or running a proxy? We had similar issue with OAuth tokens not being generated (check the URL when you get a blank page, it should have like `oauth_token=` (blank)) which generally means there's a problem with firewall or misconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

After the new Twitter API upgrade, I would recommend using the [Twitter Pull](https://drupal.org/sandbox/justindodge/2016387) sandbox project. It works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to put correct "OAuth Consumer key" and "OAuth Consumer secret" from admin/config/services/twitter/settings

Comment: Thanks Sharef, I had managed to do that bit....it seems to talk one way to twitter, but can't cope with the return handshaking.  IS there a need to set some kind of special "context" do you know?